# Can we count Processing as Environment for Mathematical Modelling and Programming?

Tags: java, processing, modeling, math

Can we count [Processing](http://processing.org/) as Environment for Mathematical Modelling and Programming? And If yes can we do the same for  Eclipse (Java)?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Can we say that  Processing is an Environment for Mathematical Modelling and Programming?

Comment: should you put them on your resume if you're proficient in them?  sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you provided:

> Processing is an open source
>   programming language and environment
>   for people who want to program images,
>   animation, and interactions.

That's not inclusive of everything that I'd call mathematical modeling.  When I hear that term, I think of linear algebra representations of physics problems in solid and fluid mechanics, electromagnetics, and heat transfer.  I doubt that Processing can do all that without a great deal of effort, but I'll admit that I didn't pore over the docs to ascertain that fact.

I would not call Eclipse an "Environment for Mathematical Modelling and Programming", unless you write a plug-in and framework for such things.  It's an IDE for Java.

Comment: Actually it's for some resume... Aughtors of resume included "matlab", "matcad", "Visual C (Visual Studio)" so I wonder If I could include Processing or they just are kiding and I have to delete somehow Visual C from options?

Comment: Do you mean "authors" and "kidding"?  If it's their resume, you can't delete anything.  All you can do is ask about what they've done with it to determine if it's appropriate.  You can do mathematical modeling with MATLAB for sure.  MathCAD is from Parametric Technologies, which is a 3D parametric CAD/CAM tool.  Visual C?  You'll have to ask the candidate to explain.  My first thought is "not appropriate".

Answer (score 3):

I worked in a Bio-Math lab for a while and I used Processing to create visualizations of mathematical models. It doesn't have the built in libraries for graphs and visualization like R, Matlab, or Mathematica, but I used it to demonstrate and teach differential equation models of disease spread, population dynamics (non-linear differential equations), genetic algorithms, and cellular automata.

With the toxiclibs set of community libraries it supports some physics stuff (including particle simulation, networks, diffusion-limited aggregation, reaction-diffusion systems, etc).

I suppose I would ask the candidate for examples of the work they did with Processing. It can be used for mathematical modeling, but it's certainly not the first thing that jumps to mind.